# Print Common Values for columns pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have csv file with data

```
                                  ID   address             used_at   active_seconds
0   bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09  avito.ru 2014-03-17 00:24:47    148  
1   bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09  avito.ru 2014-03-17 01:08:29    34  
2   bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09  avito.ru 2014-05-02 17:47:39    22  
3   bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09  avito.ru 2015-01-03 01:37:05    224  
4   bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09     e1.ru 2015-01-11 03:49:50    54   
5   bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09  avito.ru 2015-03-10 22:11:01    26   
6   bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09  avito.ru 2015-03-25 03:02:07    22 
7   690ef4613fd977f9c29e1124b9d5814c  avito.ru 2014-02-05 09:25:56    6  
8   690ef4613fd977f9c29e1124b9d5814c  avito.ru 2014-03-18 11:27:49    244 
9   690ef4613fd977f9c29e1124b9d5814c  avito.ru 2014-04-02 09:01:50    634  
10  690ef4613fd977f9c29e1124b9d5814c  avito.ru 2014-04-04 15:44:50    4206 
11  690ef4613fd977f9c29e1124b9d5814c  avito.ru 2014-04-08 09:30:25    196
12  690ef4613fd977f9c29e1124b9d5814c  avito.ru 2014-05-11 02:09:27    50
13  690ef4613fd977f9c29e1124b9d5814c  avito.ru 2014-05-17 14:41:51    838
14  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a     e1.ru 2014-01-05 13:35:19    2038
15  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a     e1.ru 2014-01-05 17:12:48    170
16  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a     e1.ru 2014-01-06 01:16:08    136
17  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a     e1.ru 2014-01-07 23:06:52    657
18  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a     e1.ru 2014-01-09 22:43:05    170
19  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a   drom.ru 2014-01-09 20:09:21    44
20  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a     e1.ru 2014-01-10 18:42:42    54
21  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a     e1.ru 2014-01-12 12:19:20    880
22  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a     e1.ru 2014-01-13 19:38:59    462
23  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a     e1.ru 2014-01-17 18:48:06    590
24  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a   drom.ru 2014-01-17 18:31:04    996
25  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a   auto.ru 2014-01-17 18:46:28    26
```

I need to print quantity of same and different ID to every address. 
For example

```
 3   bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09  avito.ru 2015-01-03 01:37:05    224  
 4   bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09     e1.ru 2015-01-11 03:49:50    54
```

There are one user(ID) visited two sites. I need to print all the same unique users for every pair of website to 2014 and 2015. It looks like `avito.ru  el.ru - 1 common user at 2014`
I don't understand How can I do it, because all means are in 2 column and they not separately. And I need print relust for 2014 and 2015 year separately(this file include only 2014 and 2015 years). [file with all data](https://yadi.sk/d/A_9pykgVqJ6Ky)

Comment: Your questions is a little unclear. Are you trying to find the number of users that are common between pairs of addresses (1 between avito.ru & e1.ru, 3 between drom.ru & avito.ru, etc.?)

Comment: Yes. But I have a task: I need to identify the main competitors(websites) and I have a file to do it. [the file](https://yadi.sk/d/A_9pykgVqJ6Ky)

Comment: I need to see all common means for example of avito and remaining websites.

Comment: @Idevyataykina - Can you create sample with 8 - 10 rows and add desired output, which better explain what do you want? Or maybe with all `25` rows?

Comment: I have a file. I should print the quantity of ID to Website, for example, Avito. And next I should find the quantity all of the users to every website, whose ID coincide with ID Avito. Is it clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
print df.groupby(['address', df['used_at'].dt.year])['ID'].nunique().reset_index(name='a')
    address  used_at  a
0   auto.ru     2014  1
1  avito.ru     2014  2
2  avito.ru     2015  1
3   drom.ru     2014  1
4     e1.ru     2014  1
5     e1.ru     2015  1

df1=df.groupby(['address',df['used_at'].dt.year])['ID'].value_counts().reset_index(name='b')
print df1

    address  used_at                                ID  b
0   auto.ru     2014  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a  1
1  avito.ru     2014  690ef4613fd977f9c29e1124b9d5814c  7
2  avito.ru     2014  bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09  3
3  avito.ru     2015  bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09  3
4   drom.ru     2014  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a  2
5     e1.ru     2014  4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a  9
6     e1.ru     2015  bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09  1
```

EDIT:

I found intersection of both `Series` and fill `DataFrame` with lengths of final `Series` with names of all combinations:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.read_csv("avito_trend.csv", 
                      parse_dates=[2])


def f(df):
    dfs = []
    for x in [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(df['address'].unique(), 2)]:

        c1 = df.loc[df['address'].isin([x[0]]), 'ID']
        c2 = df.loc[df['address'].isin([x[1]]), 'ID']
        c = pd.Series(list(set(c1).intersection(set(c2))))
        dfs.append(pd.DataFrame({'a':len(c), 'b':' and '.join(x)}, index=[0]))
    return pd.concat(dfs)

print df.groupby([df['used_at'].dt.year]).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True, level=1).reset_index()
```

```
    used_at     a                                    b
0      2014  1364                   avito.ru and e1.ru
1      2014  1716                 avito.ru and drom.ru
2      2014  1602                 avito.ru and auto.ru
3      2014   299           avito.ru and avtomarket.ru
4      2014   579                   avito.ru and am.ru
5      2014   602             avito.ru and irr.ru/cars
6      2014   424       avito.ru and cars.mail.ru/sale
7      2014   634                    e1.ru and drom.ru
8      2014   475                    e1.ru and auto.ru
9      2014   139              e1.ru and avtomarket.ru
10     2014   224                      e1.ru and am.ru
11     2014   235                e1.ru and irr.ru/cars
12     2014   154          e1.ru and cars.mail.ru/sale
13     2014   874                  drom.ru and auto.ru
14     2014   247            drom.ru and avtomarket.ru
15     2014   394                    drom.ru and am.ru
16     2014   423              drom.ru and irr.ru/cars
17     2014   292        drom.ru and cars.mail.ru/sale
18     2014   243            auto.ru and avtomarket.ru
19     2014   408                    auto.ru and am.ru
20     2014   409              auto.ru and irr.ru/cars
21     2014   330        auto.ru and cars.mail.ru/sale
22     2014   133              avtomarket.ru and am.ru
23     2014   139        avtomarket.ru and irr.ru/cars
24     2014   105  avtomarket.ru and cars.mail.ru/sale
25     2014   223                am.ru and irr.ru/cars
26     2014   166          am.ru and cars.mail.ru/sale
27     2014   197    irr.ru/cars and cars.mail.ru/sale
28     2015  1153                   avito.ru and e1.ru
29     2015  1473                 avito.ru and auto.ru
30     2015  1491                 avito.ru and drom.ru
31     2015   403             avito.ru and irr.ru/cars
32     2015   205           avito.ru and avtomarket.ru
33     2015   256       avito.ru and cars.mail.ru/sale
34     2015   262                   avito.ru and am.ru
35     2015   451                    e1.ru and auto.ru
36     2015   539                    e1.ru and drom.ru
37     2015   148                e1.ru and irr.ru/cars
38     2015   105              e1.ru and avtomarket.ru
39     2015   105          e1.ru and cars.mail.ru/sale
40     2015    99                      e1.ru and am.ru
41     2015   799                  auto.ru and drom.ru
42     2015   288              auto.ru and irr.ru/cars
43     2015   162            auto.ru and avtomarket.ru
44     2015   195        auto.ru and cars.mail.ru/sale
45     2015   224                    auto.ru and am.ru
46     2015   277              drom.ru and irr.ru/cars
47     2015   175            drom.ru and avtomarket.ru
48     2015   189        drom.ru and cars.mail.ru/sale
49     2015   187                    drom.ru and am.ru
50     2015    73        irr.ru/cars and avtomarket.ru
51     2015    94    irr.ru/cars and cars.mail.ru/sale
52     2015   102                irr.ru/cars and am.ru
53     2015    48  avtomarket.ru and cars.mail.ru/sale
54     2015    72              avtomarket.ru and am.ru
55     2015    73          cars.mail.ru/sale and am.ru
```

Comment: The first is quantity of unique users. But second not unique. I try explain: I need to find how many unique users(ID) are the same for each pair of sites. for example this user visited `3   bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09  avito.ru 2015-01-03 01:37:05    224  
4   bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09     e1.ru 2015-01-11 03:49:50    54 ` 2 webcite. In this `1ID = 2 address`. I need to find all of this users to each pair of websites

Comment: Can you add code to queston, because in comment it is bad readable?

Comment: I've attached the file with data and added more explanation. If you don't understand me, write to me, please

Comment: Can you open a file with data and see the first 8 strings. This is 1 `ID` and 8 visiting `address`. I need to print, for example for this 8 strings, that `avito.ru and el.ru` have 1 common `ID` in 2015 and 0 common `ID` in 2014. I think in your result I see common ID, but not Unique. If 1 `user` has visited 1 `address` many times, i should consider only 1 times

Comment: I think you can add after row with `read_csv` - `df = df.drop_duplicates(['ID','address'])` [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and you can check it by `print dfs2[0][dfs2[0].ID == 'bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09']`

Comment: Can you explain me, what means in dfs2 and dfs1? I've stucked. dfs1 - it's all of views?

Comment: `dfs1` is list of all `df` and `dfs1[0]` means first item of list - first `df`.

Comment: you use mean of `df1` - quantity all of reviews websites by one user. I don't need in all reviews. I need in 1 reviews by user. I want to know how many users visit pair of sites. For example I visit facebook, stackoverflow and others and I'am a one user. It's not important, how many times I open there. So I need to find a common user to every pair of website to reseach competitors

Comment: Sorry, but I still dont understand. I have an idea. Can you bring these test data `d = {'year': {0: 2014, 1: 2015, 2: 2014, 3: 2014, 4: 2015, 5: 2015, 6: 2014}, 'ID': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'b', 4: 'b', 5: 'b', 6: 'b'}, 'address': {0: 'a1', 1: 'a1', 2: 'a2', 3: 'a1', 4: 'a1', 5: 'a2', 6: 'a2'}}
print pd.DataFrame(d)` and try show recommended output? Maybe you can add few rows, if it is necessary. Because without recommended output helping is very problematic. I know, prepare sample data is not easy, but in the end it is easy verifiable and if it works well, can be used big files.Thank you

Comment: `a1 & a2 in 2014 return 2` because user with `ID a and b` visited website `a1` and `a2` in `2014`. and in `2015`.  `a1 & a2 return 2`. It is not important, how many times they open website. if we have `d = {'year': {0: 2014, 1: 2015, 2: 2014, 3: 2014, 4: 2015, 5: 2015, 6: 2014, 7: 2015, 8: 2015, 9: 2014, 10: 2015}, 'ID': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'b', 4: 'b', 5: 'b', 6: 'b', 7: 'c', 8: 'c', 9: 'c', 10: 'c'}, 'address': {0: 'a1', 1: 'a1', 2: 'a2', 3: 'a1', 4: 'a1', 5: 'a2', 6: 'a2', 7: 'a1', 8: 'a2', 9: 'a2', 10: 'a1'}}` then `2014: a1 & a2 return 2` and `2015^ a1 & a2 return 3`,Is it clear?

Comment: So desired output of  `pd.DataFrame(d)` is `print pd.DataFrame({'count': {0: 2, 1: 3}, 'year': {0: 2014, 1: 2015}, 'address': {0: 'a1 & a2', 1: 'a1 & a2'}})` ?

Comment: I was given 3 question to analyze this document(Imagine yourself on the development manager , say , drom.ru site , and try to answer the question): 
1. Where does your audience go?
2. Who is the audience for your donor ?
3. What about the players in the market , " the same " (strongly compete with each other , have a large number of general users ) , and which are more unique ?

Comment: I have an idea) when we `users = infile.groupby(["address", infile['used_at'].dt.year])['ID'].nunique().reset_index(name='users')`, we get unique users for every website and 2014 and 2015 year. For example, to `avito.ru` it's `5460` to 2014 and `4631` to 2015. I need to know how many of those `5460` in `2014` watched other websites? and print result to every pairs with `avito.ru`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107028/discussion-between-jezrael-and-ldevyataykina).

Comment: Can you answer me in our chat?

Comment: Why I have this error? `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfe' in file C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/main.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
`

Comment: Is your file `main.py` save as `UTF-8`? If not and you need different encoding, in first row of file add `#!/usr/bin/python` and second row `# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-` where `iso-8859-15` is your encoding (maybe your encoding is different, so it change up to you)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107403/discussion-between-jezrael-and-ldevyataykina).

Comment: how can I print graphic like this [example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/abQhl.png) where different color is 2014 and 2015 year. But there are no percent, but there are is mean of column

Comment: Now I have other error `Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/untitled1/new.py", line 5, in <module> 
parse_dates=[2]) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 529, in parser_f 
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 305, in _read 
return parser.read() 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 763, in read 
ret = self._engine.read(nrows) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1276, in read`

Comment: Now it `
Connected to pydev debugger (build 145.260)

Process finished with exit code 0
` but no printing in console

Comment: Phuuu, maybe try reinstall python. I use anaconda and it works very well.

Comment: I download Anaconda, but I don't know, what folder should contain `avito_trend.csv`?

Comment: After installing anaconda you can use spyder, which is installed together with anaconda. In spyder only open your python file and it works. Install pandas in anaconda is by `conda install pandas`

Comment: In spyder `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: when I delete `parse_dates=[2]` it print this file. but with this argument it returns an error

Comment: Can you download team viewer? [link](https://www.teamviewer.com/ru/) and press `Бесплатная полная версия` in green

Comment: Team viewer? Why? I dont understand. But now I am only on my mobile phone, because I am visiting parents of my wife. My pc is at home :-(.

Comment: Sorry( When I print `
df = pd.read_csv("avito_trend.csv")` it returns `[498429 rows x 1 columns]`. There is 1 columns. Maybe, problem it this?

Comment: Is separaror of columns `,` what is default separator of read_csv? If separator is `;` add parameter `df = pd.read_csv("avito_trend.csv", sep=';')`

Comment: I feel very sorry for my carelessness. My `avito_trend.csv` was changed and it have 1 colamns. I download the first file and all works

Comment: Super. It sometimes happen. No problem.

Comment: Can you say, when your last string with print i did equal to `common users` and next `graph_by_common_users = common_users.pivot(index="b", columns="used_at", values"b")` it return answer, but something return `Nan`, because some of pairs have different sequence, for example for in `2014` year there is pair of `am.ru and cars.mail.ru/sale`. But in `2015` there is `cars.mail.ru/sale and am.ru`. How can change this place?

Comment: Can you help me with my question?

Comment: Sorry I am still without PC because I still am visiting my wife's parents.